# How to ask someone for a picture taken with you?

Tags: conversation

Say, I meet a famous person and want to have a picture with them, what is the proper way to ask? Here's some of my own proposals:

- Could I take a picture of us?
- Could I take a picture with you?

Are they correct in this case? Do they sound natural?

Comment: Can I take a selfie of us?

Comment: Or *Could I take a picture **of me** with you?*  Which people would *sometimes* have said decades ago (before smartphone cameras and selfie sticks), even if what they *actually* meant was *Can I **ask someone else** to use my camera to take a picture of me and you?*

Comment: So in short, if I want a selfie, I say, "Could I take a selfie of us?", if I want somebody else to take the photo for me, I say, "Could I take a picture of me with you?", am I right?